# New to GraphQL, getting this error, Error: Show.resolve field config must be an object

Tags: graphql

This is my schema.js file.  I followed a tutorial so not sure where I went wrong.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!  This is the error message in the terminal:

Error: Show.resolve field config must be an object

Again not sure I went wrong as I'm new to GraphQL.

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const _ = require('lodash')
const Show = require('../models/show')
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLID, GraphQLInt, GraphQLList } = 
graphql

const ShowType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Show',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        genre: { type: GraphQLString },
        year: { type: GraphQLInt },
        poster: { type: GraphQLString },
        resolve(parent, args) {
            // return _.find(users, { id: parent.userId } )
            return Show.findById(args.id)
        }   
    })
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        show: {
            type: ShowType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Show.findById(args.id)
            }
        },
        shows: {
            type: new GraphQLList(ShowType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                // return shows
                return Show.find({})
            }
        }
    }
})

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addShow: {
            type: ShowType,
            args: {
                name: { type: GraphQLString },
                genre: { type: GraphQLString },
                year: { type: GraphQLInt },
                poster: { type: GraphQLString },
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                let show = new Show({
                    name: args.name,
                    genre: args.genre,
                    year: args.year,
                    poster: args.poster,
                })
                return show.save()
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: A resolver function should be associated with a particular field. Look at your fields for `Show` -- does that look right? What's different about that field config compared to your other types (other than the fact that it's a function -- that part is fine).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Daniel Rearden, can you please elaborate?  Thanks.

Comment: I took out the resolve funtion in the ShowType, not sure if that is the correct fix, but it's working now.

Comment: You can't have a resolver for a type -- only fields have resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

because you cannot put a resolve function into the the child object.

ex.

```
var bookschema = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'book',
    fields : ( ) => ({
        name : {type : GraphQLString},
        genre : {type : GraphQLString},
        id : {type : GraphQLID },
        auther : {
            type : Autherschema,//it is a another schema.
            resolve(parent,args)
            {
                return _.find(Authers,{id : parent.autherid})
            }
        }
    })
});
```

in my example 'Autherschema' is a another schema and i called as auther in parent schema you miss out that.